# Who designed the Batman balloons?

Tags: batman-1989

In the 1989 movie "Batman", who designed the balloons?
They seem like something Tim Burton would have designed, and look a lot like his designs and drawings, but I couldn't find a confirmation of this anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's circumstantial but I've been able to find these concept storyboards from the 1989 film. They were disposed of as part of a "[Tim Burton Memorabilia auction](https://gothamtrending.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/batman-storyboards-original-artwork-joker-concept-art-movie-production-burton-memorabilia-auction.jpg)". You can see the crude lines of the balloons as well as the fact that several are different from their final film incarnations.

[image]

Based on the initials on the boards, I would say that it's highly likely that the design of the balloons was a collaborative effort between TB (Tim Burton) and MW (Michael White)

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks a great deal! It's so good to be able to understand the process...

Comment: @randal'thor - My goal was to hit 10K by New Year and 15K within the following quarter. I'm still on-track. Honestly though, I've just not seen that many interesting question in the last few weeks that I wanted to devote large amounts of time to.

Comment: @Richard You'll like this: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34011/what-are-the-cons-and-the-pros-of-using-the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-as